# question on a positive series

Tags: calculus, real-analysis, sequences-and-series

Let $a_n$ be a positive series with $a_n-a_{n+1}\geq \beta a_{n}^{2-\alpha}$ for some positive constant $\beta>0$ and $\alpha\in(0,1]$.

I guess that 
$$
\sum_{n\geq 1} a_n<+\infty.
$$
First it is easy to see that $a_n$ is decreasing and that $\lim a_n=0$.
For the case $\alpha=1$, we can see that
$$
\sum_{n\geq 1} a_n\leq a_1<+\infty.
$$
How to show the convergence for the general case in which $\alpha\in (0,1)$?